# How to use cx_Freeze to make an executable python program

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I downloaded cx_Freeze because I'm trying to make a .exe file to share with my platoon and I've been reading through the [docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils) as well as scrolling through [cx_Freeze tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-python-scripts-exe-executables/?completed=/threading-tutorial-python/). After following both of those I still don't know why this isn't working for me. I'm on Python 3.6.2 and I have the path directly setup to the command line.

I tried to launch with setup.py and Julian date 2.py on the desktop and I tried adding them to same folder, but no matter what I try I get back this error when I type `python setup.py build`, `python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Error2] no such file or directory or file exsists`. Below is my setup.py code.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name = "Julian date 2" ,
    version = "0.1" ,
    description = "" ,
    executables = [Executable("Julian date 2.py")])
```

Another issue I ran into was trying to type `cxfreeze Julian date 2.py --target-dir dist` I get the error `'cxfreeze' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you type python setup.py build, you are supposed to be in the directory with setup.py and not anywhere else. So use the command cd  to get there.
2. cx_freeze is not in your path variable so cxfreeze Julian date 2.py --target-dir dist will not work and you have to instead add it to your path (somehow) [not recommended]

Hope this helped.

P.S.
executables = [Executable("Julian date 2.py")]) takes base too. If you want a console application:
executables = [Executable("Julian date 2.py",base='None')])
Gui for windows:
executables = [Executable("Julian date 2.py",base='Win32GUI')])

And you forgot your exe options in setup(). I recommend adapting the setup.py script on cx_freeze doxs:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).

base = "None"

setup(  name = "name",
        version = "0.1",
        description = " ",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("file.py", base=base)])
```

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the first issue**, my file was named 'setup.py' and not just 'setup' as it's supposed to be...The name must be setup, the extension .py

Know it's DUMB, after hours, that was the problem...